# OpenCV + Android: how to access the camera in JavaCameraView

Tags: java, android, opencv

Maybe a very stupid question. Anyway, I'm trying to get into OpenCV on Android devices. Therefore I'm playing around with the examples of the OpenCV Android SDK. My problem is, that my code in the MainActivity which uses a JavaCameraView instance. That instance has a private member which is the actual camera.

I want to access the camera in the JavaCameraView.surfaceChanged event to use code like that? So question a) how to hook on that event and b) how to access the camera member?

Here's some example code from [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11336315/converting-nv21-to-rgb-using-opencv-in-android):

```
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {

    Size size = params.getPreviewSize();
    this.height = size.height;
    this.width = size.width;
    camera.setParameters( params );
    camera.startPreview();

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution I found was to inherit from JavaCameraView or NativeCameraView to gain access to it's protected camera member.

Comment: do you have some sample code? I'm trying to access the Camera so I can record using `MediaRecorder`. Any advice?

Comment: No, sorry. But you can just look at the source code of OpenCV for Android.

Comment: You can see the source code here: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/samples/android/tutorial-3-cameracontrol/src/org/opencv/samples/tutorial3